# Navbar from rails application disappears when deploying to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, navbar

I have been building a Rails application that I am deploying to Heroku, I had installed a navbar to navigate around the app and it was working completely fine until recently. Now the navbar is not showing up on the application even though it still works perfectly when I try anything locally. I have tried rake assets:precompile, bundle install, and all the usual suspects. I don't know what to do exactly. I have attached screenshots of my app in testing and production. [This is the image of the two apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tecqG.png). This error first turned up when I created an account on the production application on Heroku. The logs show this error
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap")

Comment: Have you checked the logs ?

Comment: Yes, I was getting this error. 

2021-04-12T02:24:58.493556+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2021-04-12T02:24:58.493479 #4] FATAL -- : [9c9b6d9a-4543-45ca-890c-adaf051f5cd0]   
2021-04-12T02:24:58.493572+00:00 app[web.1]: [9c9b6d9a-4543-45ca-890c-adaf051f5cd0] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap")

Answer (score 1):

So if a public/assets/manifest.yml(Rails 4 uses a file called public/assets/manifest-.json instead) is detected in your app, Heroku assumed you are handling asset compilation yourself and will not attempt to compile your assets.  On both versions you can generate this file by running $ rake assets:precompile locally and checking the resultant files into Git.

This means that I ran rake assets:precompile locally, even just once, and then checked in that manifest file that  would then need to run assets:precompile and check the results into git before every deploy. It's quite a subtle change that can catch people out.

Removing the public/assets/manifest.yml file from my git repo and re-deploying the app, so that asset compilation is done automatically by Heroku again solved the error.